# Angularfire2 Authentication: How to get the current user?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

In my angular-app I am using angularfire2 Authentication.
When opening a certain window, I want to get the email of the current user.

To this end, I wrote the following code:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.currentUserEmail = this.angularFireAuth.authState
      .switchMap(user => {
          console.log("this is a test");
          return user.email;
      });

}
```

The code follows the documentation here:
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/google-user-auth-with-firestore-custom-data/#Step-3-Auth-Service

However, for some reason, the part after "switchMap" is never entered".
So the line "this is a test" gets never printed.

How can I get the current user (and his/her email)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine.

```
constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth){}

this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        // logged in or user exists
      }
      else {
        // not logged in
      }
})
```

Note: At above, It will trigger every time when auth state have changed (sign-in, sign-out)

Another way to get user:

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
   if (user){

   }
   else{

   }    
})
```

You also can get another user data. For the email you can call 'user.email'
[image: get email]